# Change color InputLabel Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following input label:

```
<InputLabel>NAME</InputLabel>
```

My problem is that the text is in White (I don't get why is white, maybe I am doing something wrong), and I can't see white on white. How do I change the color to black?

Answer (score 8):

You can give the `<InputLabel />` a className:

```
<InputLabel classname="test-label">This is a label</InputLabel>
```

In your stylesheet:

```
.test-label: {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

---

If you are trying to style the `<InputLabel />` through a `<TextField />` component

You can give the `<InputLabel />` a class by accessing the `<TextField />` InputLabelProps:

```
<TextField
   label="This is a label"
   InputLabelProps={{
     className: "test-label" 
   }}
/>
```

In your stylesheet:

```
.test-label: {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Was styling through a TextField component, this helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```js
<TextField
   label="This is a label"
   InputLabelProps={{
     className: classes.formLabel 
   }}
/>

  formLabel: {
    color: '#000,
    '&.Mui-focused': {
      color: '#000
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `withStyles` and `classes` property. Have a look at [overriding with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides#overriding-with-classes) section and the [implementation of the component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui/src/InputLabel/InputLabel.js) for more detail.

Read the API of [InputLabel here](https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/).

Create a required styles

```js
const styles = theme => ({
 
  cssLabel: {
    color:'blue',//required color
    
  },
  
  )}
```

Apply the styles using `FormLabelClasses` property.

```js
<InputLabel
          FormLabelClasses={{
            root: classes.cssLabel,
            focused: classes.cssFocused,
          }}
          htmlFor="custom-css-input"
        >
          Custom CSS
        </InputLabel>
```

Don't forget to import `withStyles`.

Refer [Customised input](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#customized-inputs) in documentation itself.

Answer (score 2):

What’s up? After looking for the answer it was as simple as

```
<Box>
          <TextField
            onChange={handleChange("quantity")}
            label="$ Quantity"
            variant="filled"
            InputLabelProps={{
              style: { color: "cadetblue" }
            }}
          />
        </Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `style` for the below tag as follows;

```
 <InputLabel style="color:black;">NAME</InputLabel>
```

or

Add the following for `InputLabel` in CSS and try:

```
InputLabel{  
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: In Chrome browser , Right click on the 'InputLabel' element and perform 'Inspect'  and see the 'styles' mapped for that InputLabel

Comment: Also please try this, means, this will ignore subsequent rules and apply this rule!' `InputLabel{  
  color: black !important;`
}

Answer (score 0):

react.js?

try use

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
};
<InputLabel style={divStyle} >NAME</InputLabel>
```

Answer (score 0):

The color of the input label doesn't necessarily remain when it's in focus, and will be overridden by the defaults. The way that I solved this and to get the font colour to remain the same was by doing the following in typescript:

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
    formText: {
        color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText, 
        '&$formLabelFocused': {color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText}
    },
    formLabelFocused: {
    }
})

class Example extends React.Component<>{
    public render() {
           <FormControl>
                    <InputLabel 
                        FormLabelClasses={{                        
                            root: classes.formText,
                            focused: classes.formLabelFocused
                        }}
                    >
                        Currency
                    </InputLabel>
          </FormControl>
          <Select>
                    <MenuItem key={1}>Example</MenuItem>
          </Select>
    }
}
```

I struggled with many variations on this before getting the right workaround

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
};
<InputLabel style={divStyle} >NAME</InputLabel>
```